# How do I find a value in a row and return the column number with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

My excel sheet is filled with zeroes except for one cell in every row.
I want to find that cell and return the column.
For example: In the cell T616 is a value other than 0. May it be -15400.
I want to find that cell(T616) based on the row(616) and have the column returned(T). May it even be in a MsgBox.
This is my result of many tries and long Google-sessions:

```
Public Function find_Column(lRange As Range, lValue As String) As Integer
Dim vCell As Range

For Each vCell In lRange.Cells

If vCell.Value = lValue Then
find_Column = vCell.Column
MsgBox (find_Column)
Exit Function
End If

Next vCell

End Function
```

I found this code somewhere and modified it a little bit, but I can't remember where. So thanks to the creator!
How do I search for a number other than 0?
I'm relatively new to VBA and don't really have an idea what I am doing. Sorry for my bad English (foreigner). I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: If vCell.Value <> 0 Then ?

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<>` symbol is the "Not Equal" Comparison. So if you wanted to check if a cell didn't equal 0, you would write

```
If vCell.Value <> 0 Then
    ... ' rest of code here
```

In your problem:

```
Public Function find_Column(lRange As Range) As Integer
    Dim vCell As Range

    For Each vCell In lRange.Cells

        If vCell.Value <> 0 Then
            find_Column = vCell.Column
            MsgBox (find_Column)
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next vCell

End Function
```

Also since you are only checking against 0, you wouldn't need the extra `lValue As String` argument.

Comment: Thank you! Seems logical to me.
So if i want to call the function it could look like this:
    Call find_Column(Range(Cells(5, 616), Cells(103, 616)))
?

Comment: The Cells function is a bit counterintuitive, where it actually works like `Cells(Row, Column)` instead of `Cells(X, Y)` like you would probably expect. So if you are searching between `column 5` and `column 103` on `row 616`, hopefully `find_Column(Range(Cells(616, 5), Cells(616, 103)))` should work.

Comment: There we got my misconception. Thank you very much! It works now, great!

Comment: @butterb3an No problem. If any of the answers people provided helped you, consider checking the tick mark underneath the arrows to mark it as the chosen answer. That way in the future, people can find the answer they need quicker, and it helps out the people who gave the answer in the first place. Once again, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Function findNonZeroValueInColumn(lRange As Range) As Integer
 Dim vCell As Range

 For Each vCell In lRange.Cells

  If vCell.Value <> 0 Then
   find_Column = vCell.Column
   Exit Function
  End If

 Next vCell

End Function

Sub ShowValue()
  call  MsgBox(findNonZeroValueInColumn(Range("A:A")))
End Sub
```

Remember that Functions are supposed to return values. Subs (Procedures) do not return values.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try and put that into my code.

Answer (score 0):

As the other part of your question has been answered while I was typing, if you want to return the column letter instead of the number...

```
find_Column = Replace(Replace(vCell.Address, vCell.Row, ""), "$", "")
```

If this is what you want the function to return, you would have to change the type your function is returning to string